# Simple question about $\nabla f(\mathbf x).(\mathbf y - \mathbf x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For the function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$, why if $\nabla f(\mathbf x)\cdot (\mathbf y - \mathbf x)\le 0$ for all $\mathbf x$, then $\mathbf y$ maximizes $f(\cdot)$? 
I know $\nabla f(\mathbf x)\cdot (\mathbf y - \mathbf x)$ is proportional to directional derivative of $f(\cdot)$, and a negative value means reduction in the value of the point, but I am looking for a simple *high-school* description.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "high-school description"? It seems like you already have an intuitive understanding of the question; do you want a *proof* understandable at the high-school level?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something that is simple to describe to someone with little background in math.

Answer (score 0):

The standard interpretation of $\nabla f(\mathbf x)\cdot (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})$ is "rate of change of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$ when moving with velocity $\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}$."

If you think about the geometry of the problem, you should be able to convince yourself that if we draw $\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}$ as an arrow starting at $\mathbf{x}$, we will obtain an arrow that points from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{y}$.

So we can reinterpret $\nabla f(\mathbf x)\cdot (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})$ as "the rate of change of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$ when moving towards $\mathbf{y}$." This means "$\nabla f(\mathbf x)\cdot (\mathbf y - \mathbf x)\le 0$ for all $\mathbf{x}$" translates to  "$f$ never increases when we move towards $\mathbf{y}$". Or, more simply, "$\mathbf{y}$ minimizes $f$". (note: either I've made a mistake, or you've copied your question wrong.)